# When I run a return () ? "" : "" syntax in Javascript, I receive an error in Google Chrome ONLY when I save the file as a PHP and not as HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to programming in general and stumbled upon an error that I cannot solve by myself.  I create a HTML file incorporating `<script>` tags and then a function running a `return () ? "" : ""` syntax and everything works fine in my browser.  However, when I put the exact same code within PHP tags I am getting the above error in Google Chrome that says ""Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return"" and specifies the line with the `return () ? "" : ""` syntax.  The exact same code is being saved to a PHP file but is surrounded by `<?php   ?> tags`.  Code in HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>An Example </title>
    <script>
      function validateForename(field)
      {
        return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\n" : ""
      }

    </script>
  </head>

</html>
```

Code in PHP file is:

```
<?php
echo <<<_END
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>An Example </title>
    <script>
      function validateForename(field)
      {
        return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\n" : ""
      }

    </script>
  </head>

</html>

_END
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the contents of your php file, we need the full 'story' of the code so we need as much information as you can provide.

Comment: Thank you.  My question has been edited with the full code comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable

Arguments must be passed as `$var_name`.You're missing a `$` here. Also note you must end the statement by `;`

Try this:

```
<?php
function sample($name){return ($name == "") ? "None./n" : "";}
    echo 'Hello ', 'World!' , '<br />'.sample('');      
?>
```

As you are `echoing` entire string using `php`, it will treat `\n` as new line. Escape that character using `\\`. For example: `(return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\\n" : "")`

Comment: Sorry about that.  Just edited my question with the code comparison in full.

Comment: Also note, `php`=> `HyperTextPreprocessor` will parse `\n` as new line. Escape that character using this: `return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\\n" : ""`

Comment: The original code only had "field" and not "$var_field".  I attempted an edit after your initial comment and forgot to change back to the original code before placing it into my question.  Question now has original code in which everything is the same except "$var_field" is now "field".  Thanks

Comment: I removed the /n and it now works!  Thank you so much.

Comment: That is not really needed. Escape it using `\\` and that is it..I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forget to type $ before variable names and semicolon after line. you should use $name instead of name and type semicolon after "".

```
function sample($name){return ($name == "") ? "None./n" : "";}
```